# GUI in VR for Google Cardboard in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm creating simple google cardboard game in unity and i want to add score count. I know how to do it normally, but in VR it doesn't work for me. I tried to just put Text and display score in it, and it looked good(not exactly because it was displayed only for one eye) but after I tested it on my phone text was in completely different place. Do you know what's the proper way to do it?

Comment: Do you watch the app cardboard design from cardboard, there are many tips or exp for vr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a World Space canvas and have that canvas attached to the camera. Thats how I get my UI in VR games.

You're going to need a custom shader for your World Space UI objects that has it's Render Order to Overlay and has ZTest turned off.

This is a copy of the Default UI shader with the necessary changes. Should do the trick. Just make a material with this shader, and apply it to everything you want drawn over the top of geometry in your WorldSpace UI.

```
 Shader "UI/Default_OverlayNoZTest"
 {
     Properties
     {
         [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
         _Color ("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)

         _StencilComp ("Stencil Comparison", Float) = 8
         _Stencil ("Stencil ID", Float) = 0
         _StencilOp ("Stencil Operation", Float) = 0
         _StencilWriteMask ("Stencil Write Mask", Float) = 255
         _StencilReadMask ("Stencil Read Mask", Float) = 255

         _ColorMask ("Color Mask", Float) = 15
     }

     SubShader
     {
         Tags
         { 
             "Queue"="Overlay" 
             "IgnoreProjector"="True" 
             "RenderType"="Transparent" 
             "PreviewType"="Plane"
             "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
         }

         Stencil
         {
             Ref [_Stencil]
             Comp [_StencilComp]
             Pass [_StencilOp] 
             ReadMask [_StencilReadMask]
             WriteMask [_StencilWriteMask]
         }

         Cull Off
         Lighting Off
         ZWrite Off
         ZTest Off
         Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
         ColorMask [_ColorMask]

         Pass
         {
         CGPROGRAM
             #pragma vertex vert
             #pragma fragment frag
             #include "UnityCG.cginc"

             struct appdata_t
             {
                 float4 vertex   : POSITION;
                 float4 color    : COLOR;
                 float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
             };

             struct v2f
             {
                 float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
                 fixed4 color    : COLOR;
                 half2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
             };

             fixed4 _Color;

             v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
             {
                 v2f OUT;
                 OUT.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, IN.vertex);
                 OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
 #ifdef UNITY_HALF_TEXEL_OFFSET
                 OUT.vertex.xy += (_ScreenParams.zw-1.0)*float2(-1,1);
 #endif
                 OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
                 return OUT;
             }

             sampler2D _MainTex;

             fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
             {
                 half4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) * IN.color;
                 clip (color.a - 0.01);
                 return color;
             }
         ENDCG
         }
     }
 }
```

credit goes to http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/878667/world-space-canvas-on-top-of-everything.html

Comment: Do you do it like this? http://imgur.com/VLTSEmF It works fine but how do you make this UI always visible(it sometimes hides behind something in my game)?

Comment: I think it's not mandatory to apply this shader with the new Unity 5.4. Can someone confirm ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say; setup a RenderTexture and make your/the UI the only thing drawn onto it, then stick the RenderTexture onto something else in your world